# LaTeX table floating off page

Tags: tables

We have a table that has 7 columns. We are trying to get to fit the page, but it will not do so. Do you have any suggestions as to how we might get this to fit either horizontally or vertical.

[http://imgur.com/a/9NYcA](https://imgur.com/a/9NYcA)

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|ll}
    \cline{1-6}
    \textbf{Communication task}  & \textbf{Audience}                                             & \textbf{Objectives/ Goals}                                                                                                     & \textbf{Tools/ Resources Needed}                                                               & \textbf{Method of communication}                              & \textbf{Outcome}                                                                             &  &  \\ \cline{1-6}
    Initial Group Meeting        & Project group                                                  & Exchange contact details\\and establish group \\weaknesses and strengths                                                          & Notes                                                                                          & Face-to-face                                                  & Group chat created                                                                           &  &  \\ \cline{1-6}
    Arrange meeting with sponsor & Communications leader and Sponsor                              & Establish meeting time                                                                                                         &                                                                                                & Email                                                         & Meeting arranged with sponsor                                  &  &  \\ \cline{1-6}
    Group meeting                & Project group                                                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Read project brief\\ Discuss questions to ask sponsor\end{tabular}                                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Project brief\\ Notes\end{tabular}                                  & Face-to-face                                                  & List of questions to ask sponsor                                                             &  &  \\ \cline{1-6}
    Meeting with sponsor         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Project team\\ Sponsor\end{tabular} & Clarify the project requirements                                                                                               & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Audio recording\\ \\ OneDrive\end{tabular}                          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Email\\ Face-to-face\end{tabular}  & Established project requirements                                                             &  &  \\ \cline{1-6}
    Team meeting                 & Project team                                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Division of tasks for formative coursework\\ Test blackboard collaboration application\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Coursework brief\\ OneDrive\\ Blackboard collaboration\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Face-to-face\\ Webcam\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tasks allocated \\ Established how to work BB collab\end{tabular} &  &  \\ \cline{1-6}
    &                                                                &                                                                                                                                &                                                                                                &                                                               &                                                                                              &  &  \\ \cline{1-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: you need to make columns narrower. this can be done by broken cells text into more line. For this you need to change column type, for example to `p{<width>}` or use `tabularx` and his column type `X`.

Comment: Could you show me how please? I am very new to latex and been using for a few weeks.

Comment: When you respond to someone outside of an answer they authored, you must get their attention like so:  @Zarko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your table is really huge ... below is MWE with four possible solutions. In all are used smaller fonts, two of them is in portrait orientation, two in landscape. For second two the table is transposed with hope to obtain more space for text in cells.

For table environment is used `tabularx` with modified `X` columns (`\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}`). The cells width is left equal, however with some manual tweaking (as it is done in the last example)  the better cells spacing can be obtained.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{6}{L|}}
    \hline
\thead[b]{Communica-\\ tion task}  
    &   \thead[b]{Audience}                        
        &   \thead[b]{Objectives/\\ Goals}                        
            &   \thead[b]{Tools/\\ Resources\\ Needed}
                &   \thead[b]{Method of\\ communication}                              
                    &   \thead[b]{Outcome}                 
                        \\ \hline
Initial Group Meeting        
    &   Project group                            
        &   Exchange contact details and establish group weaknesses and strengths
            &   Notes
                &   Face-to-face  
                    &   Group chat created  
                        \\ \hline
Arrange meeting with sponsor 
    &   Communications leader and Sponsor        
        &   Establish meeting time                            
            &   
                &   Email   
                    & Meeting arranged with sponsor    
                        \\ \hline
Group meeting                
    &   Project group                            
        &   Read project brief\newline
            Discuss questions to ask sponsor  
            &   Project brief Notes
                &   Face-to-face
                    &   List of questions to ask sponsor                                                             
                        \\ \hline
Meeting with sponsor         
    &   Project team Sponsor
        &   Clarify the project requirements 
            &   Audio recording OneDrive
                &   Email Face-to-face
                    &   Established project requirements 
                        \\ \hline
Team meeting                 
    &   Project team
        &    Division of tasks for formative coursework\newline
             Test blackboard collaboration application
            &   Course work brief\newline
                OneDrive Blackboard collaboration
                &    Face-to-face Webcam
                    &   Tasks allocated Established 
                        how to work BB collab
                        \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label-2}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{6}{L|}}
    \hline
\thead[b]{Communication\\ task}
    &   \thead[b]{Audience}
        &   \thead[b]{Objectives/Goals}
            &   \thead[b]{Tools/Resources\\ Needed}
                &   \thead[b]{Method of\\ communication}
                    &   \thead[b]{Outcome}
                        \\ \hline
Initial Group Meeting
    &   Project group
        &   Exchange contact details and establish group weaknesses and strengths
            &   Notes
                &   Face-to-face
                    &   Group chat created
                        \\ \hline
Arrange meeting with sponsor
    &   Communications leader and Sponsor
        &   Establish meeting time
            &
                &   Email
                    & Meeting arranged with sponsor
                        \\ \hline
Group meeting
    &   Project group
        &   Read project brief\newline
            Discuss questions to ask sponsor
            &   Project brief Notes
                &   Face-to-face
                    &   List of questions to ask sponsor
                        \\ \hline
Meeting with sponsor
    &   Project team Sponsor
        &   Clarify the project requirements
            &   Audio recording OneDrive
                &   Email Face-to-face
                    &   Established project requirements
                        \\ \hline
Team meeting
    &   Project team
        &    Division of tasks for formative coursework\newline
             Test blackboard collaboration application
            &   Course work brief\newline
                OneDrive Blackboard collaboration
                &    Face-to-face Webcam
                    &   Tasks allocated Established
                        how to work BB collab
                        \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\bfseries}L|*{5}{L|}}
    \hline
Communication task
    &   Initial Group Meeting
        &   Arrange meeting with sponsor
            &   Group meeting
                &   Meeting with sponsor
                    &   Team meeting
                        \\ \hline
Audience
    &   Project group
        &   Communications leader and Sponsor
            &   Project group
                &   Project team Sponsor
                    &   Project team
                        \\ \hline
Objectives/ Goals
    &   Exchange contact details and establish group weaknesses and strengths
        &   Establish meeting time
            &   Read project brief\newline
                Discuss questions to ask sponsor
                &   Clarify the project requirements
                    &    Division of tasks for formative coursework\newline
                         Test blackboard collaboration application
                        \\ \hline
Tools/ Resources Needed
    &   Notes
        &
            &   Project brief Notes
                &   Audio recording OneDrive
                    &   Course work brief\newline
                        OneDrive Blackboard collaboration
                        \\ \hline
Method of communication
    &   Face-to-face
        &   Email
            &   Face-to-face
                &   Email Face-to-face
                    &    Face-to-face Webcam
                        \\ \hline
Outcome
    &   Group chat created
        &   Meeting arranged with sponsor
            &   List of questions to ask sponsor
                &   Established project requirements
                    &   Tasks allocated Established
                        how to work BB collab
                        \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\setlength\hsize{0.85\hsize}\bfseries}L|
                              >{\setlength\hsize{0.95\hsize}}L|
                              >{\setlength\hsize{0.90\hsize}}L|
                              >{\setlength\hsize{0.90\hsize}}L|
                              >{\setlength\hsize{0.90\hsize}}L|
                              >{\setlength\hsize{1.50\hsize}}L| }
    \hline
Communication task
    &   Initial Group Meeting
        &   Arrange meeting with sponsor
            &   Group meeting
                &   Meeting with sponsor
                    &   Team meeting
                        \\ \hline
Audience
    &   Project group
        &   Communications leader and Sponsor
            &   Project group
                &   Project team Sponsor
                    &   Project team
                        \\ \hline
Objectives/ Goals
    &   Exchange contact details and establish group weaknesses and strengths
        &   Establish meeting time
            &   Read project brief\newline
                Discuss questions to ask sponsor
                &   Clarify the project requirements
                    &    Division of tasks for formative coursework\newline
                         Test blackboard collaboration application
                        \\ \hline
Tools/ Resources Needed
    &   Notes
        &
            &   Project brief Notes
                &   Audio recording OneDrive
                    &   Course work brief\newline
                        OneDrive Blackboard collaboration
                        \\ \hline
Method of communication
    &   Face-to-face
        &   Email
            &   Face-to-face
                &   Email Face-to-face
                    &    Face-to-face Webcam
                        \\ \hline
Outcome
    &   Group chat created
        &   Meeting arranged with sponsor
            &   List of questions to ask sponsor
                &   Established project requirements
                    &   Tasks allocated Established
                        how to work BB collab
                        \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Below is result of the first and the last example, other you can see with test of whole MWE:

[image]

[image]